# Is there any way to retrieve the chef node specific parameters available in data bag

Tags: chef-infra

Hi i have the parameters in my chef databag which is encrypted.
Now i want some parameters to be displayed from chef data bag
is there any way or command similar for that

Comment: Normally i created multiple json files in which each json file consist of information about one chef node. so now i have 35 json files and i want one parameter in each json file to be retrived from a single script, is that possible

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve a data bag item and decrypt it using [`knife`](https://docs.chef.io/knife_data_bag.html#show):

> `$ knife data bag show DATA_BAG_NAME (options)`
>
> This argument has the following options:
>
> - `DATA_BAG_ITEM`
>     The name of a specific item within a data bag.
> - `--secret SECRET`
>     The encryption key that is used for values contained within a data bag item. If secret is not specified, the chef-client looks for a
>     secret at the path specified by the encrypted_data_bag_secret setting
>     in the client.rb file.
> - `--secret-file FILE`
>     The path to the file that contains the encryption key.

Answer (score 0):

The above query is for the single databag properties to retrive but what about multiple data bags at a time is there any command or script for that i have tried several combinations but i am unable to retrive the data.

i mean to sat that
lets put all the data bag names passed in a variable and that variable is called with in the script along with the knife command is there any possibility like that.